# Do other languages use things like Foo, Bar; Spam, Eggs

Tags: variables, language-agnostic, coding-style

In languages like Java, Javascript, C, C++, C#, I have seen code similar to the folowing in tutorials and code snippets.

```
int foo = 5;
int bar = 10;
baz(foo, bar);
```

I assume these are used for quick variable names when naming conventions do not really need to be followed, such as quick snippets, but they have become so popular, they seem to be part of the language. For example, python has traded `foo` and `bar` for `spam` and `eggs`.

```
spam = 'spam'
eggs = 'eggs'
spam_and_eggs(spam, eggs)
```

When I see these variable names, I instantly think of python and no other language. Do other languages have **signature** placeholder variable names such as python?

Comment: doubt it's the right type of question for SO ...

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are also used by Objective-C.

Comment: The correct word is ["metasyntactic"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable).

Answer (score 6):

These variables aren't generally part of the languages at all, they're called meta-syntactic variables and allow you to use variables in example code without having to think *too* hard about what it should be called.

I tend to use something similar, calling all my source files `qq.c` or `qq.py` (for example) when testing one-shot code for Stack Overflow.

The [Jargon file](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/index.html) lists a [decent variety](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html) of these (including their likely etymology) but, unfortunately, fail to list my personal favorites, `xyzzy`, `plugh`, `twisty` and `passages`, in order of preference and use, and showing my age :-)